# clean postal address with regex (spark regexp_extract)

Tags: python, regex, pyspark

I want to cut the end of some addresses :
"1 rue de l'église" => "1 rue de l'église"
"2 rue de la poste appartement B" => "2 rue de la poste"
"3 4 rue de la mairie 2eme étage" => "3 4 rue de la mairie"

The rule is: if a number or a keyword ("appartement" or "escalier") is found in the middle of the address, then cut the address just before.

The beginning is obviously like "`^([0-9 ]*`", but I can't say "take the characters if there is no number OR 'appartement' OR 'escalier'".

One of my tries :

```
my_df.select("adresse_rue").withColumn(
    "adresse_rue", 
    f.regexp_extract(
        "adresse_rue",
        r'^([0-9 ]*[^(0-9| appartement | escalier )]*)([0-9]| appartement | escalier )?.*$',
        0)).take(20)
```

Perhaps `?:` and `?!` could help but I didn't find how.

Comment: I doubt this can be done with a regex since street names may contain digits (rue des 24 arpents, rue du 8 mai 1945). A more rigorous approach is to use a database with street names and to check if the address exists once you have identified the different parts. Don't forget that an address may be also a simple *lieu-dit*.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track with regular expressions. You can use a [negative lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) assertion `(?!pattern)` to achieve the desired result. Here's how you can modify your regular expression:

```
r'^(?:(?! +(?:\d+[a-z]|appartement|escalier)).)*'
```

Explanation:

- `(?:\d+[a-z]|appartement|escalier)` matches your keyword ("appartement", or "escalier", or any sequence of digits followed by a latin letter).
- `(?! +(?:\d+[a-z]|appartement|escalier))` means "not followed by at least one space and the keyword".
- `(?:(?! +(?:\d+[a-z]|appartement|escalier)).)*` does this check just before each matched character.

See a [demo @ regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hYNokG/1).

**EDIT**

If you also want to exclude any digit (e.g. "2" other than "2eme") after the first ones, use instead the following expression:

```
r'^[\d ]*(?:(?! +(?:\d|appartement|escalier)).)*'
```

Moreover, if you also want to exclude digits occurring in the middle of words (like "A2"), use te following expression:

```
r'^[\d ]*(?:(?! +(?:[^\s]*\d|appartement|escalier)).)*'
```

See a second demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/hYNokG/3).

Comment: I upvoted this answer but don't think it has fully met the requirement in OP. Numbers without trailing letters are not getting filtered out. For example, `1 2 abc 3 d` should yield `1 2 abc`, but yields `1 2 abc 3 d` instead.

Comment: @ChrisFu My impression was that the OP just wanted to exclude french ordinals (like "2eme"). Anyway, I have clarified this aspect in the answer, thank you for having pointed it out.

Comment: Yes, I have done some adjustments, but it's exactly what I needed. Thank you